# Disable word wrap using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, text-files, word-wrap

Is it possible to turn off word wrapping in text files using .htaccess?  I have thousands of .txt files and don't want to have to change all of them to html files just so that I can disable wrapping.  I've tried changing the mime-type, but haven't found anything to work.  Most browsers these days wrap text by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, .htaccess has nothing to do with word wrap.

But what you can do with .htaccess is, redirect all requests to a serverside script that opens requested text file and responds it as an unwrapped html.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I think I understand most of the concept, but could you give an example?  Thank.

Comment: You have to add something like this codes to the .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]`

So that every url request will open index.php.

And in index.php, you will take the request url, get the requested text file name from it, open that file, and then print contents of that text file inside nowrap styled html div.

Comment: Mahmut.  I didn't immediately see how that would have worked, so I elected a different approach. In .htaccess:`RedirectMatch (.*)\.txt$ textdisplay.php?file=$1.txt`
In the .php file, inside <pre>: `echo file_get_contents("$_GET['file']);`  It's a solution at least.  If there is a better way let me know.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was just trying to give you the idea, I just copied and pasted that .htaccess from my project :D Your solution is not an '_enough solution at least, meh_'. It is the true solution.